# High Vulnerability Detected in Dependency (NPM debug) of mocha

Tags: security, mocha.js, checkmarx, npm-vulnerabilities, npm-debug

How to Remediate: Vulnerability Detected in debug package (Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity)

I recently ran a security scan using Checkmarx One and detected a high vulnerability in the npm debug package.

**Package**: debug

**Version**: 4.3.4 (latest)

**CWE**: CWE-1333 (Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity)

**Description**: In NPM debug, the enable function accepts a regular expression from user input without escaping it. Arbitrary regular expressions could be injected to cause a Denial of Service attack on the user's browser, otherwise known as a ReDoS (Regular Expression Denial of Service). This is a different issue than CVE-2017-16137.

I did not directly install and use the debug package. It is a dependency of the following packages that I am currently using:

- mocha @ 10.2.0
- mocha-junit-reporter @ 2.2.0
- supertest @ 6.3.3
- hygen @ 6.2.11

Is there any recommended remediation for this vulnerability?

[Screenshot of Checkmarx One description of the Vulnerability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6sdJ.png)

Comment: Did you got any solution for ths ?

Comment: Did you get any solution to fix this?